# Как запустить запрос мутаций в BioSAMTools?

Tags: ruby, gems

Как запустить запрос мутаций в BioSAMTools?

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby

require 'bio-samtools'
bam = Bio::DB::Sam.new(:bam => "my.bam", :fasta => 'fake.fa')
bam.open
bam.mpileup do |pileup|
   puts pileup.consensus
   bam.flag_stats()
   bam.close
end
```

Comment: Здравствуйте. Ваш вопрос все-таки больше специализированный, требует специальных знаний, терминологии, не связанной с программированием, больше шансов получить на подобные вопросы на biostarts.org (англоязычный), bioinf.help (русскоязычный), или в других подобных местах.
Вообще по смыслу похоже, что pileup должен возвращать вам, кроме консенсусного значения, нуклеотиды по текущей позиции. Конечно, если вы именно это подразумеваете под словосочетанием "запрос мутаций". Если нет, поясните, пожалуйста, что вы имели в виду.

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что не по теме ru.so

Comment: oni ne znayut i russkih ottuda  s biostars gonyat, zakrivauit account....

Comment: @VassiaAlk а вы им на каком языке писали? как они узнали что вы - русский??

Comment: Конкретизируйте вопрос, что выдаёт этот код, ошибку или что?